# ¿Por qué no ordena ascendentemente y descendentemente de forma correcta?

Tags: c, codeblocks

Realizo un programa que ordena de forma ascendente y descendentemente un arreglo, el arreglo es cargado y declarado por el usuario. Bueno, lo que sucede es que cuando lo ejecuto no ordena de forma correcta el arreglo, tengo que ejecutarlo por segunda ves(a través de un do while) para que lo logre, y bueno, me gustaría que lo haga a la primera."

```
 switch (opc){
        case 1:
            printf("As%c luce su arreglo ordenado ascendentemente: ",161);
            for(int e=1; e<=n; e++){
                    for(int j=0; j<n-1; j++){
                        if(ord[j]>ord[j+1]){
                            temp=ord[j];
                            ord[j]=ord[j+1];
                            ord[j+1]=temp;
                        }
                    }
                  printf("\n%i",ord[e]);
        }

            break;

        case 2:
            printf("As%c luce su arreglo ordenado descendentemente: ",161);
             for(int e=1; e<=n; e++){
                    for(int j=0; j<n-1; j++){
                        if(ord[j]<ord[j+1]){
                            temp2=ord[j];
                            ord[j]=ord[j+1];
                            ord[j+1]=temp2;

                        }
                    }
                    printf("\n%i",ord[e]);

         }
            break;
```

[image: Foto de la ejecución]

Comment: ¿Puedes dejar un ejemplo de cómo está ordenando el arreglo? Puede facilitarnos ayudarte. Supongamos que introduces `2, 1, 3` y obtienes `1, 2, 3` (ascendente).

Comment: Ya  subí la imagen espero se vea soy nuevo en esto, ahora me manda basura al final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código ordena bien el arreglo.

El error que cometes es ir imprimiendo sus elementos cuando todavía no terminó de ordenarlos.

Imprime el arreglo y verás que está bien. Pero solo cuando hayas terminado de ordenarlo. Puedes crear una función incluso:

```
void print(int* arr, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d, ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Otra cosa, tal como imprimes ahora el arreglo, cuando `e = n`, el código imprime un elemento que no existe. Las posiciones de los elementos van de 0 a n-1.

Aquí me refiero:

```
for(int e=1; e<=n; e++){
    ...
    printf("\n%i", ord[e]); \\ <--
}
```

---

Alternativamente, si quieres imprimir los elementos mientras los ordenas, puedes usar otro método de ordenación que en cada iteración ubique un elemento en el lugar correcto. Por ejemplo **Selection Sort**.